# All string literals are show in small case in Tapestry 5

Tags: tapestry

I am new to tapestry5 (5.3.6) and having issue while displaying labels and text.

```
<h1>
      <t:pagelink page="index">First Tutorial</t:pagelink>
</h1>
```

The above tag always shows as "first tutorial", tapestry always shows every thing in small case.

Any idea how to configure tapestry to retain the case of the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tapestry does not modify text case. You should check your css to see if there is any `text-transform:lowercase` rule applicable to the element.

Comment: @srinik, you ought to mark that answer as the correct answer then :)